# Is there a bijection from a bounded open interval of $\mathbb{Q}$ onto $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

It is easy to create a bijection between two bounded open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, such as:

$$
\begin{align}
 f : (a,b) &\to (\alpha,\beta) \\
 x &\mapsto \alpha+(x-a)(\beta-\alpha).
\end{align}
$$

It is also possible to biject a bounded open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ onto the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, e.g.:

$$
\begin{align}
 f : (a,b) &\to \mathbb{R} \\
 x &\mapsto \tanh^{-1} x.
\end{align}
$$

Consider now the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. The bijection between two bounded open intervals still holds, but is it possible to biject:
$$
f : (p,q) \to \mathbb{Q}
$$

where $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $(p,q) = \{x\in \mathbb{Q} : p < x < q\}$?

Comment: Do you just want a bijection, or rather an order isomorphism?

Comment: I would suspect so--there are a countably infinite number of rationals between any two distinct real numbers, and so there must be a bijection between such an interval and $\Bbb Q$--but I don't know how to construct one.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I would be happy to see either/both.

Comment: @Fargle I suspect the same because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense like $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see. I also needed 0 to be in the open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ for my function to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question: ([Is there a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves rationality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17568/is-there-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-mathbbr-that-preserves-rationality?rq=)) -- that is, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} - 2$ for $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(x) = 2 - \frac{1}{x - 1}$ on $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ -- is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\Bbb R$ that preserves rationality; then $f|_{\Bbb Q}$ is a bijection from $(0,1)_{\Bbb Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

I'm not sure how this could be extended to general $(p,q)$, but this is an example of one function for one such interval.

EDIT: as Whacka has pointed out, simply by composing this function with a bijection from $(0,1)_{\Bbb Q}$ to $(p,q)_{\Bbb Q}$, this may be achieved. One such map is $x \mapsto (q-p)x + p$, whose inverse is $x \mapsto \frac{x - p}{q - p}$.

So in general, a bijection from $(p,q)_{\Bbb Q}$ to $\Bbb Q$ is:

$f(x) = \frac{q - p}{x - p} - 2,\;x \in (p, \frac{p+q}{2})$

$f(x) = 2 - \frac{q - p}{x - q},\;x \in [\frac{p+q}{2}, q)$

Comment: One may compose the isomorphism $\Bbb Q\cong(0,1)$ with an isomorphism $(0,1)\cong(p,q)$. (This is implicit in my answer.) Constructing the latter isomorphism is quite simple: choose the appropriate affine map $x\mapsto ax+b$ for rationals $a,b$.

Comment: @whacka: You know, that should've been obvious. Good point!

Comment: The composition does not work if either or both of $ p, q $ is irrational.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo The original post specifically states $p,q \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Sure. Still, that's an unnecessary assumption.

Answer (score 6):

Cantor showed that any two countable densely ordered sets with no first or last element are order isomorphic. One can build the isomorphism using his [Back and Forth Method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method)

If all we want is a bijection, we can more simply note that both sets are countably infinite.

Comment: If the interval is bounded but closed --- i.e. $[p,q]$ --- is there still a bijection but no longer an order isomorphism?

Comment: @MGA There is a bijection because they are the same cardinality, but they are not isomorphic as ordered sets because the closed interval $[p,q]$ has a maximum and a minimum, whereas $\Bbb Q$ has no such elements. (The existence or nonexistence of such purely-ordered-theoretically defined things is an invariant.)

Comment: I believe an unstated aim in the OP is to have an order preserving *monotonic* bijection.

Answer (score 4):

Start: Pick any monotonic decreasing sequence $l_i$ of positive rationals converging to zero and any monotonic increasing sequence $r_i$ of positive rationals converging to $1$, with $l_1<r_1$. Consider

$$\begin{array}{lllll} \Bbb Q= & \cdots & \sqcup & [2,-1) & \sqcup & [-1,0) & \sqcup &  [0,1) & \sqcup & [1,2) & \sqcup & [2,3) & \sqcup & \cdots \\
(0,1) = & \cdots & \sqcup & [l_3,l_2) & \sqcup & [l_2,l_1) & \sqcup & [l_1,r_1) & \sqcup & [r_1,r_2) & \sqcup & [r_2,r_3) & \sqcup & \cdots \end{array} $$

Note that $[a,b)\cong[c,d)$ are order-isomorphic for any rationals $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Q$ with $a<b$, $c<d$.

All intervals are taken in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

I know similar ideas already came up here, but the first thing I thought of was to construct the bijection $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow(-2,2)$ given by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-2-\frac{1}{x}&x\in(-\infty,-1)\\
x&x\in[-1,1]\\
2-\frac{1}{x}&x\in(1,\infty)
\end{cases}
$$
with explicit inverse
$$
f^{-1}(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{x+2}&x\in(-2,-1)\\
x&x\in[-1,1]\\
\frac{1}{2-x}&x\in(1,2)
\end{cases}
$$
and then this could be composed with a linear bijection $g:(-2,2)\longrightarrow(p,q)$.