# Do the adeles $\mathbb{A}$ have the same cardinality as the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: number-theory, cardinals, p-adic-number-theory

My question today is about the Adeles and whether they have the same cardinality as the real numbers.

---

Certainly $\mathbb{R}$ has more elements than $\mathbb{Z}$.  This is by Cantor diagonalization.  Here are some interesting twists I have read on that discussion (not important now)

- [Is there a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves rationality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17568/is-there-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-mathbbr-that-preserves-rationality?rq=1)
- [Bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243544/bijection-between-mathbbr-and-mathbbr-mathbbq?rq=1)
- [Why do the rationals, integers and naturals all have the same cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182236/why-do-the-rationals-integers-and-naturals-all-have-the-same-cardinality) (most important)

We also know that p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.  You can imagine that allowing infinitely many digits to the **left** of the decimal point should be the same as allowing them to the right.

What happens when we multiply all of them?  I made the mistake of writing an equality here:

$$ \mathbb{A} \neq \prod \mathbb{Q}_p$$

Instead the Adeles are a "restricted product" of all p-adic numbers over all primes $p = 2,3,5,7,11,13\dots$ :

$$  \mathbb{A} = \Big\{ (x_2, x_3, x_5, \dots,x_p, \dots ) \in \prod \mathbb{Q}_p  \Big| \text{ most of }  x_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p \Big\} $$

Is the "size" or "number of" Adeles stricly larger than $\mathbb{R}$?  Certainly the straight product would be bigger:

$$ |\mathbb{A}| \leq \left|\prod \mathbb{Q}_p \right| = \left| \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} \right| $$

Since we only have the **restricted product**... how big is this set exactly? How does it compare to more familiar sets like $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Z}$ or $2^\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cardinal arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131212/overview-of-basic-results-on-cardinal-arithmetic) tells us $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{Z}|}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\times \aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb{R}|$.

And $|\mathbb{R}|\le|\mathbb{A}|\le|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ implies $|\mathbb{A}|=|\mathbb{R}|=\mathfrak{c}$.