# Bijective correspondence from all irrational numbers to irrational numbers of any open interval?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

Can you example a Bijective correspondence from all irrational numbers to irrational numbers of any open interval (for example (0, 1) interval)? Is it even possible?

\begin{equation}
f: \mathbb{Q}^{c} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{c} \cap (a, b) \\
\end{equation}

Comment: If you want actual examples, which are in some sense "smooth" I'd start [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational?_gl=1*m1kxup*_ga*MTQ0MzQ5NDU0LjE2NzQ2NjM5NjU.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3NzkzMDQzNy4xOTMuMS4xNjc3OTQ1NDkxLjAuMC4w)

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17568/is-there-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-mathbbr-that-preserves-rationality) is a near duplicate.

Comment: To be clear:  I seriously doubt that there is a "pleasant" solution.  The methods discussed in the first link I provided give you something, but it sure isn't pretty.  If there is something sensible, please post it as an answer here.  I'd like to see it.

Comment: So, post the solution for rational $a,b$.  I think that would be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only for when a and b are both rational.

Consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/900763/684235) function and call it f.
f is defined on (0, 1).

It can be shown that the sum and product of rational and (rational/irrational) are (rational/irrational).

so define g(x) := (x - a) / (b - a)
since a and b - a are both rational, we can say fog(x) is still smooth.
So fog(x) is the answer for this case.